# Flutter Firestore: how to get id's for documents in a list

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling to figure out how to get id's for a list of items. I know I can get a single document and get the id, but for a list, not sure how to do it? Below I want my list to return the id along with the name for each ProductType

```
  Future<List<ProductType>> getProductTypes() async {
    var query = await collection.get();
    return query.docs.map((e) => ProductType.fromJson(e.data())).toList();
  }



  ProductType.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) : this(
    name: json["name"]! as String,
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QueryDocumentSnapshot.id` property to get the id of the document.

```dart
Future<List<ProductType>> getProductTypes() async {
  var query = await collection.get();

  return query.docs.map((e) => ProductType.fromJson({
    "id": e.id,
    "name": e.data()["name"]! as String,
  })).toList();
}
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html